# Smooth div “gallery” with jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, prefetch

I'm looking for an elegant and efficient solution for something that can be described as a `div`  “gallery”.

Currently we're using jQuery UI tabs and prepopulate `div`s on server. **The user only sees the active `div` and can move to next or previous tab.** However, as the list now contains more than 100 items, we would like to switch to a dynamic loading approach.

At first, I tried to separate `div`  generation for an item to an AJAX call, and use builtin Tabs AJAX functionality. However, **the glitch when moving back or forth with jQuery UI Tabs AJAX is very noticeable**. When the tab has loaded, it gets cached so it works normal again.

I have the following ideas now:

1. **Somehow prefetch next 5 tabs each time user clicks 'Next'.**

   The user isn't likely to scroll very fast, and we're okay with glitches in case of fast scrolling. All I want to do is to ensure that normally several next tabs are loaded **before** they get displayed. Is this possible with jQuery Tabs?
2. **Populate a JavaScript array on server and create `div`s on the fly.**

   This is another possible solution I'm looking into. I could've written a function to generate `div` by object data saved in JavaScript. The JavaScript could be generated by server.

Which is more appropriate? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so as I got no responses I went with the second route and it seems like a good solution.

A script in the `head` section populates globally visible `items` data list with JSON generated in-place by server.
Then, where tabs `div`s were previously defined, I put a script to generate them on-the-fly:

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs"> 
        <ul class="ui-tabs-nav"></ul>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                createTab(items[i], i);                     
        </script> 
</div>
```

`createTab` function is defined in a separate JS file and manages creating `div` and list items for `ul`:

```
function createTab(item, index) {
    createPanel(item, index).appendTo($('#tabs'));
    createTabItem(index).appendTo($('.ui-tabs-nav'));
}

// creates list item with a href="#tabs-1..n"
function createTabItem(index) {
    return $('<li></li>').append(
        $('<a></a>').attr('href', '#tabs-' + (index+1))
    );
}

// creates a div for tab
function createPanel(item, index) {
    var panel = $('<div class="ui-tabs-panel"></div>')
        .attr('id', 'tabs-'+ (index+1)); // id = "tabs-1..n"

    if (index > 0) panel.addClass('ui-tabs-hide'); // hide all tabs but the first

    // whatever you need to fill the tab with
    createPicture(item).appendTo(panel);
    createDescription(item).appendTo(panel);

    return panel;
}
```

Since all of this happens before the page is loaded, I didn't have to change the code that manages tab navigation.

Of course, this doesn't yet enable prefetching images, but makes it much easier to do, as tab creation occurs at one place and it's become easier to control.